# How to record audio mp3 javascript

Tags: javascript, audio-recording

I'm developing a web that need to record user's voice as a mp3 file. 
I have this code and it save the audio as a webm file,and the problem is that  if I download the file I can't restart the audio and I can't listen to a certain min.
this is my code :

```
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(function(microphone) {
  // preview camera during recording
  document.getElementById('your-video-id').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('your-video-id').muted = true;
  setSrcObject(microphone, document.getElementById('your-video-id'));
  // recording configuration/hints/parameters
  var recordingHints = {
      type: 'audio'
  };
  // initiating the recorder
  var recorder = RecordRTC(microphone, recordingHints);
  // starting recording here
  recorder.startRecording();
  // auto stop recording after 5 seconds
  setTimeout(function() {
      // stop recording
      recorder.stopRecording(function() {

          // get recorded blob
          var blob = recorder.getBlob();
          // generating a random file name
          var fileName = getFileName('mp3');
          // we need to upload "File" --- not "Blob"
          var fileObject = new File([blob], fileName, {
              type: 'audio/mp3'
          });
          var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(fileObject.name);
          storageRef.put(blob);
      });
  }, milliSeconds);
});
```

Comment: *"I have this code and it save the audio as a **webm** file"* change `type: 'audio/mp3'` to `type: audio/webm` perhaps?

Comment: I want the audio to be MP3 and not webm

Comment: The MIME for MP3 is `type: 'audio/mpeg'` not `'type: 'audio/mp3'`

Comment: @zer00ne Still not working with type: 'audio/mpeg'

Comment: ["move_upload_file" takes two parameters. First parameter is ~/tmp/fileName.mp3 and second parameter is "./uploads/fileName.mp3"](https://muaz-khan.blogspot.com/2017/08/recordrtc-and-upload-to-php-server.html) and keep `type: audio/mpeg`

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Yes that's a known [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642012) (extendable to an API specs one actually). No browser has native support for MP3 encoding, but it's still doable (see e.g [RecorderJS](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) which made use of the WebAudioAPI. And @zer00ne setting the mime type of the File object won't change it's content...

Comment: As @Kaiido stated MIME does not determine content, my comments are merly comments and not an answer. Regardless, the correct MIME is `audio/mpeg`